# При выборе одного селектора удаление и замена другого?

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование

Вопрос к знатокам. Имеется класс `icon-my-01. icon-my-` статическая величина `01-`динамическая.  
Надо, чтобы при выборе класса `icon-my-` заменялся класс с одного на другой, как это реализовать одинарно я разобрался, вот код:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $("#pak").hasClass("icon-my-10") ) {
  $('#puk').removeClass('icon_block').addClass('icon_block_my_big');
}
});

<h1>Welcome to My Homepage</h1>
<p class="i">My name is Donald.</p>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>
<div id=puk class="icon_block">XXXXXXX.</div>
<div id=pak class="icon-my-10">My name is Dolly.</div>
<p>I live in Duckburg.</p>

А вот как с условием фильтра не могу понят пробовал, так не работает
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $("#pak").hasClass("[class|=icon-my]") ) {
  $('#puk').removeClass('icon_block').addClass('icon_block_my_big');
}
});
```

Как можно задать в hasClass условие с фильтром, и если нельзя, то как сделать по-другому.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте так:

```
$("#pak").is("[class|=icon-my]")
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам, но эта проверка почему, то не работает вот код с вашей поправкой
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( $("#pak").is("[class|=icon-my]") {
  $('#puk').removeClass('icon_block').addClass('icon_block_my_big');
}
});
</script>

Comment: Как минимум вы пропустили скобку

if ( $("#pak").is("[class|=icon-my]") ) {

Comment: Спасибо Вам все работает!

Comment: А подскажите еще пожалуйста, как теперь это все по циклу пропустить через .each?

Comment: @Максим Герасимов, не совсем ясно, зачем вам нужен цикл.  
Если перебрать все элементы #pak, то это можно сделать так:  

    $("#pak").filter("[class|=icon-my]")
             .removeClass("icon_block")
             .addClass("icon_block_my_big");

Comment: Что вы хотите перебрать по циклу и для чего?

Comment: VenZel
Дело в том, что весь html генерируется динамически там. Через списки <li> а в них уже лежат <div> с которыми проводятся манипуляции. Выше стоящий код проделывает манипуляции один раз на остальные подобные блоки он не воздействует. Вот я и подумал, что через цикл надо гонять
И мне не совсем понятно, как должен Ваш код выглядеть в моем коде?